# Carousel images are initially displaying too small before automatically resizing correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm just using a small bootstrap carousel on a site, but it's acting a little oddly. The first image displays at the correct size but each subsequent one appears half-sized, centred at the top of the container for around half a second before resizing properly. Having reached a frustration point I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to why it might be behaving like this.

Comment: You will need to post the exact relevant libraries and code, there are many carousel libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way you can handle

This just apply one commen class for images

Then apply CSS

Specify height and width

Definitely your problem get solved..